# How to create a heat map in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create heat map in order to check which content, buttons, links clicked often and which not in SharePoint Online intranet page.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But answering as it might help somenone in future.
Please use below link to find the answer for this question:

[Build simple heatmap & mouse tracker for SharePoint Online](https://letslearnoffice365.wordpress.com/2019/01/20/build-heatmap-mouse-tracker-for-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create heat map using powerBI and put iframe in content editor.